# How turn off auto generated by master page name attribute for asp controls asp.net 4 website

Tags: visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0

For instance I have page, this is her content

```
<asp:Content runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MenuHeaderContent" ID="MenuPage">
<asp:RadioButton Text="Edit file name" runat="server" GroupName="renameOrRaplace"
                                        ID="chooseRen" CssClass="radio" />
</asp:Content>
```

I've turned off auto generate Id's, but now I have problem with autogenerated names for controls I mean that name for [input] with GroupName="renameOrRaplace" must be name="renameOrRaplace" but not name="MenuHeaderContent$renameOrRaplace"
How I can fix it, but not by javascript?

Answer (score 0):

Just add name="renameOrRaplace" to your server side ASP.NET page markup instead of using GroupName attribute

```
<asp:RadioButton Text="Edit file name" runat="server" name="renameOrRaplace"
                                        ID="chooseRen" CssClass="radio" />
</asp:Content>
```